# passing argument 1 of 'x' from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c

I try to create a void function that cant get a array of two dimensions and they can use for input and output.

The function this.

```
void Charge(float *p[15][10]){
```

And the call is this:

```
Charge(&pol);
```

The array is Float pol[15][10]

I use GCC compiler on linux

Ty.

Comment: you *can* use it for both input and output, as `Charge(float p[15][10])`, and `Charge(pol)`

Comment: `Float` is not the same as `float` (mind the capital).

Comment: Your `&` achieves nothing (and it fails because one is an array of arrays of pointers gone through an array to pointer conversion as the argument, while the other is a pointer to an array of arrays of floats)

Comment: `float *p[15][10]` is an array of 15x10 _pointers_ to float. Just remove the `*` and the `&` *See Antti's comment).

Comment: Also, this is hardly a [mcve] otherwise, and you must provide the compiler messages if any in the question and the code to reproduce those messages.

Comment: Hint: try using a `typedef` to make an array of 15x10 floats into something more manageable.

Comment: You are passing `&pol` which is `float (*p)[15][10]`, ie a pointer to an array of 15x10 floats, yet your function expects `float *p[15][10]`, ie. an array of 15x10 pointers to float.

Comment: You can either: (1) declare the function as `void Charge(float p[15][10])`, use `p[x][y]` to access the `float` at position (x,y), and call the function as `Charge(pol);`, or (2) (less common) declare the function as `void Charge(float (*p)[15][10])`, use `(*p)[x][y]` to access the `float` at position (x,y), and call the function as `Charge(&pol);`. Personally, I'd choose option (1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using gcc, you should be getting a warning like this:

> passing argument 1 of 'Charge' from incompatible pointer type | expected `float * (*)[10]` but argument is of type `float (*)[15][10]`

Meaning that the prototype should have been `void Charge(float (*p)[15][10])` - an array pointer to a `float [15][10]` rather than a 2D array of `float*` which is not what you wanted.

---

But there's not really a reason to use this array pointer syntax. It is much clearer to do like this:

```
float arr[15][10];
...
Charge(arr);
...
void Charge (float arr[15][10]);
```

Thanks to array decay, this does pass an array pointer to the function. And now you can use it inside the function as `arr[i][j]` rather than `(*p)[i][j]`.

---

Using 21th century C, you can also do this:

```
float arr[15][10];
...
Charge(15, 10, arr);
...
void Charge (size_t x, size_t y, float arr[x][y]);
```